# X10 x10.lang.FailedDynamicCheckException: !(here == x$0.home) C++ Backend

Tags: exception, x10-language

i'm playing around with X10 currently, and i'm getting multiple exceptions. This is the code i created:

Main.x10

```
public class Main {

// main Method for the Main class
public static def main(argv:Rail[String]) {
    Console.OUT.println("This is the main place. (ID="+here.id+")");
    val dataItem = new Data();
    // no global reference, data is copied to each place.
    finish for (p in Place.places()) {
        at (p) async {
            Console.OUT.println("This is place no: "+here.id+". The value of dataItem is "+dataItem.getValue()+".");
            dataItem.incValue();
        }
    }
    Console.OUT.println("Final value of dataItem without GlobalRef in multiple places at place "+here.id+": "+dataItem.getValue());
    dataItem.setValue(0);
    finish for (p in Place.places()) {
        async {
            Console.OUT.println("This is place no: "+here.id+". The value of dataItem is "+dataItem.getValue()+".");
            dataItem.incValue();
        }
    }
    Console.OUT.println("Final value of dataItem without GlobalRef in one place at place "+here.id+": "+dataItem.getValue());
    dataItem.setValue(0);
    val globalRefDataItem = GlobalRef[Data](dataItem);
    finish for (p in Place.places()) {
        at (p) async {
            val globalDataItemUnwrapped = globalRefDataItem();
            Console.OUT.println("This is place no: "+here.id+". The value of dataItem is "+globalDataItemUnwrapped.getValue()+".");
            atomic globalDataItemUnwrapped.incValue();
        }
    }
    Console.OUT.println("Final value of dataItem with GlobalRef in multiple places at place "+here.id+": "+dataItem.getValue());
}
```

}

Data.x10

```
public class Data{
private var value:Long;
def getValue():Long{
    return value;
}
def setValue(value:long){
    this.value = value;
}
def incValue(){
    this.value = this.value+1;
}
}
```

The output in X10DT is the following:

```
This is the main place. (ID=0)
This is place no: 3. The value of dataItem is 0.
This is place no: 1. The value of dataItem is 0.
This is place no: 2. The value of dataItem is 0.
This is place no: 0. The value of dataItem is 0.
Final value of dataItem without GlobalRef in multiple places at place 0: 0
This is place no: 0. The value of dataItem is 0.
This is place no: 0. The value of dataItem is 1.
This is place no: 0. The value of dataItem is 2.
This is place no: 0. The value of dataItem is 3.
Final value of dataItem without GlobalRef in one place at place 0: 4
This is place no: 0. The value of dataItem is 0.
Command used: /home/martze/x10dt/workspace/Example/bin/Main
Uncaught exception at place 0: x10.lang.MultipleExceptions
x10.lang.FailedDynamicCheckException: !(here == x$0.home)
at x10aux::throwException(x10::lang::CheckedThrowable*)
at Main__closure__3::__apply()
at x10::lang::Activity::run()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Worker::loop()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Worker::__apply()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Pool::run()
at 
at GC_inner_start_routine
at GC_call_with_stack_base
at 
at clone
x10.lang.FailedDynamicCheckException: !(here == x$0.home)
at x10aux::throwException(x10::lang::CheckedThrowable*)
at Main__closure__3::__apply()
at x10::lang::Activity::run()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Worker::loop()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Worker::__apply()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Pool::run()
at 
at GC_inner_start_routine
at GC_call_with_stack_base
at 
at clone
x10.lang.FailedDynamicCheckException: !(here == x$0.home)
at x10aux::throwException(x10::lang::CheckedThrowable*)
at Main__closure__3::__apply()
at x10::lang::Activity::run()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Worker::loop()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Worker::__apply()
at x10::lang::Runtime__Pool::run()
at 
at GC_inner_start_routine
at GC_call_with_stack_base
at 
at clone
```

I tried googling, but the results were only pointing to some documentation that didn't help me at all. My environment variables are set to X10_NTHREADS=1 and i set the number of places to 4. I'm working with Ubuntu and i'm using the C++ Backend.

What can i do about this error and what does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A  `GlobalRef` is a globally meaningful reference to an object at a particular place.  It may only be dereferenced at the place where it was created (the "home" place).  The exception is thrown at the dereferencing ('unwrapping') of the `GlobalRef`:

```
val globalRefDataItem = GlobalRef[Data](dataItem);
finish for (p in Place.places()) {
  at (p) async {
    val globalDataItemUnwrapped = globalRefDataItem();
    ...
  }
}
```

The `GlobalRef` was created at place 0, but is being dereferenced (`globalRefDataItem()`) at place `p`.  The error would be easier to understand if it read:

```
x10.lang.FailedDynamicCheckException: (here != globalRefDataItem.home)
```

To access the object that is referred to by the `GlobalRef`, the activity must change place back to the home place.  For example:

```
val globalRefDataItem = GlobalRef[Data](dataItem);
finish for (p in Place.places()) {
  at (p) async {
    at(globalRefDataItem.home) {
      atomic globalDataItemUnwrapped.incValue();
    }
  }
}
```

This is often referred to as the "ping-pong" idiom - the activity changes to a remote place and then changes back again to the original place.

In your program, there is the added requirement to print the value of dataItem *before* it was incremented.  To do this, use an *at expression* ([X10 language spec](http://x10.sourceforge.net/documentation/languagespec/x10-241.pdf) §13.3) to return a value from the remote place, for example:

```
finish for (p in Place.places()) {
  at (p) async {
    val currentValue = at(globalRefDataItem.home) {
      val globalDataItemUnwrapped = globalRefDataItem();
      var valueBeforeInc:Long = 0;
      atomic {
        valueBeforeInc = globalDataItemUnwrapped.getValue();
        globalDataItemUnwrapped.incValue();
      }
      valueBeforeInc
    };
    Console.OUT.println("This is place no: "+here.id+". The value of dataItem is "+currentValue+".");
  }
}
```

Note, I made an important change to the original code, to combine the get and increment of the value in a single `atomic` block.  Without this change, it would be possible for another activity to increment the value in between these two statements.  X10 provides atomic types (e.g. `x10.util.concurrent.AtomicLong`) which provide just such an atomic `getAndIncrement` operation.

Comment: Okay. This makes sense. But is there a way to execute the activity in the remote place, but access the data of another place? With the ping-pong idiom, isn't this copying the data to a remote place and the back, and then working? Sounds strange to me.

Comment: In general, activities may only access data which reside at the current place.
When a `GlobalRef` is sent to a remote place, all that is actually sent is a single identifier (like a pointer) which is meaningful at the home place; the actual target object is not copied.  So in ping-pong, the identifier is sent to place `p` and then back to the home place.